# Can I import html of other sites using jquery.load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I got ...
[image]

Can I import html of other sites using jquery.load into div?

Comment: you can, if other sites allows cross-site sharing. Otherwise you might have to load the other site into an `IFrame`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because the webpage you are trying to load is from a different domain than your own.

See [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

You should use Iframes instead, to load the pages from different domains.
Otherwise as target domain to allow your domain in their CORS Policies.

Comment: So is it impossible to make this work?

Comment: you can make either of the suggested changes to make that work.

Comment: read through the CORS policies doc to understand first, what's the problem, basis on that you might find a solution that fits you best.